# How to keep a TableView's selection when focus is lost?

Tags: javafx-2

How can I keep a TableView's selection when focus is lost to the Windows?

When a the focus to a window is lost, the selected item is still visibly selected in the window; however, I cannot find a way to access the selected object from its controllers.

I have tried using the TableView's methods `getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().get()` and `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` but both of these return `null` if the focus to the window and/or table is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable and set it in a change listener.  I use labels for debugging.

```
    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition> c) {
            label1.setText(String.valueOf(c.getList().get(0).getRow()));
        }
    });
```

java 8

```
    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition> c) -> {
        label1.setText(String.valueOf(c.getList().get(0).getRow()));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. I was wondering if I'd have to do something like this but didn't know how to go about it.